# Magento 2 add request header to Graphql programmatically

Tags: magento2.3, php, graphql, postman

I'm trying to run this Graphql url `https://****.***.com/in/graphql` by Postman

I saw in Magento document that the URL above can contain `Store` header
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/graphql/send-request.html

But when I check the header it does not contain `Store` attribute. And I have to add it manually.

[image]

How can I add `Store` attribute to the Header request programmatically or change the URL to get the `store_code` automatically?

Note*: all ticked fields are automatically added by default.

Answer (score 1):

> Header Key and Value graphql query postman
>
> ```
> // enter header key as 'Store' and value as store code e.g in
> Store - in
>
> // enter header key as 'content-currency' and value as store code e.g AED
> content-currency - AED
> ```

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Resolver;

use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Config\Element\Field;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Exception\GraphQlInputException;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Exception\GraphQlAuthorizationException;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Query\ResolverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Schema\Type\ResolveInfo;

class ExampleClass implements ResolverInterface
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function resolve(
        Field $field,
        $context,
        ResolveInfo $info,
        array $value = null,
        array $args = null
    ) {
        // get store and currency from graphql
        $store = $context->getExtensionAttributes()->getStore();
        $currency = $store->getCurrentCurrencyCode();
        $store = $store->getCode();

        $data = $offer->getData();
        $data['model'] = $offer;

        return ['offer' => 'test data'];
    }
}
```